# Error building opencv: internal compiler error: in gt_pch_note_object

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I need to build an older OpenCV version and I have been stuck with it for days. Any help is appreciated.

The configuration I get from CMake:

```
General configuration for OpenCV 2.4.11 =====================================
  Version control:               unknown

  Platform:
    Host:                        Windows 10.0.19044 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.24.3
    CMake generator:             MinGW Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            C:/Tools/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe
    Configuration:               Release

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ Compiler:                C:/Tools/mingw64/bin/c++.exe  (ver 8.1.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -mstackrealign -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -ffunction-sections -O2 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -mstackrealign -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -ffunction-sections -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  C:/Tool/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe
    C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -mstackrealign -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -ffunction-sections -O2 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -mstackrealign -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -ffunction-sections -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):      
    Linker flags (Debug):        
    Precompiled headers:         YES

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 core flann imgproc highgui features2d calib3d ml video legacy objdetect photo gpu ocl nonfree contrib stitching superres ts videostab
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 androidcamera dynamicuda java python viz

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI: 
    QT:                          NO
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    OpenGL support:              NO
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.7)
    JPEG:                        build (ver 62)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.5.12)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)

  Video I/O:
    Video for Windows:           YES
    DC1394 1.x:                  NO
    DC1394 2.x:                  NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      codec:                     YES (ver 55.18.102)
      format:                    YES (ver 55.12.100)
      util:                      YES (ver 52.38.100)
      swscale:                   YES (ver 2.3.100)
      gentoo-style:              YES
    OpenNI:                      NO
    OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
    PvAPI:                       NO
    GigEVisionSDK:               NO
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            NO
    XIMEA:                       NO
    Intel PerC:                  NO

  Other third-party libraries:
    Use IPP:                     NO
    Use Eigen:                   NO
    Use TBB:                     NO
    Use OpenMP:                  NO
    Use GCD                      NO
    Use Concurrency              NO
    Use C=:                      NO
    Use Cuda:                    NO
    Use OpenCL:                  YES

  OpenCL:
    Version:                     dynamic
    Include path:                C:/opencv-2.4.11/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Use AMD FFT:                 NO
    Use AMD BLAS:                NO

  Python:
    Interpreter:                 C:/Tools/Python27/python.exe (ver 2.7.15)

  Java:
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Documentation:
    Build Documentation:         NO
    Sphinx:                      NO
    PdfLaTeX compiler:           NO
    Doxygen:                     NO

  Tests and samples:
    Tests:                       YES
    Performance tests:           YES
    C/C++ Examples:              NO

  Install path:                  C:/opencv/install

  cvconfig.h is in:              C:/opencv
```

After I configure & generate with CMake (for MinGW Makefile), I am trying to build with `mingw32-make --debug` in the build folder. I am on Windows 10 & GNU Make 4.2.1 & CMake 3.24.3 & OpenCV 2.4.11 is downloaded from https://opencv.org/releases/page/7/.

The error I am getting:

```
[ 19%] Generating precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_core_Release.gch
D:/opencv_mingw32/modules/core/precomp.hpp:202:1: internal compiler error: in gt_pch_note_object, at ggc-common.c:276
 }
 ^
libbacktrace could not find executable to open
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64> for instructions.
mingw32-make[2]: *** [modules\core\CMakeFiles\pch_Generate_opencv_core.dir\build.make:75: modules/core/precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_core_Release.gch] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:1693: modules/core/CMakeFiles/pch_Generate_opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:165: all] Error 2
```

To be honest, this error does not tell me anything, neither can I find info online. The guides for building older OpenCV are pretty difficult to find as well. So, as I wrote in beginning, any help would be very valuable. I have to stay on this version of OpenCV.

Comment: You probably want to update your old version of MinGW. Uninstall it and use msys2 to install the latest version. [https://www.msys2.org/#installation](https://www.msys2.org/#installation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is your compiler telling you that you managed to hit an internal compiler bug. "Internal compiler error" means exactly what it says. Congratulations, I suppose... There are no workarounds, short of manually editing the code, guessing what's triggering the bug, and editing the C++ source code to produce something different, but logically equivalent and it does not trigger the internal compiler bug, whatever it is.

The shown version of gcc, version 8, is extremely old. Try to see if you can update your toolchain to a more recent version of gcc. The current version of gcc is 13.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to compile it by combining gcc 12 with OpenCV 2.4.13.4.